# Why google index this?

Tags: seo, search-engine, web-crawler, robots.txt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why google index this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862702/why-google-index-this)

In this webpage:

http://www.alvolante.it/news/pompe_benzina_%E2%80%9Ctruccate%E2%80%9D_autostrada-308391044

there is this image:

http://immagini.alvolante.it/sites/default/files/imagecache/anteprima_100/images/rifornimento_benzina.jpg

Why this image is indexed if in the robots.txt there is "Disallow: /sites/" ??

You can see that is indexed from this search:

http://www.google.it/images?q=rifornimento+benzina&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=it&tab=wi&biw=1280&bih=712

.

P.S. robots.txt is in the domain [alvolante.it](http://www.alvolante.it/robots.txt) and in the subdomain [immagini.alvolante.it](http://immagini.alvolante.it/robots.txt)

P.P.S. This is NOT my website... so I can't use google webmaster tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this image has been hotlinked by another website, google will crawl it - despite its original domain's robots.txt

There is really not much you can do, despite trying to avoid hotlinking through .htaccess or some other form of redirection or IIS directive. However, as you are not owner of the original site, these alternatives might not be viable.